# How to run rspec tagged tests when using bundle exec rspec spec?

Tags: rspec, tags

When I want to run tagged tests I use

```
rspec spec --tag smoke_test_not_present
```

I get an error about older gems on my system.  A familiar error.

The solution that is listed and usually works is to pre-pend with `bundle exec`

I want to run tagged tests.

So I do:

```
bundle exec rspec spec --tag smoke_test_not_present_this_does_not_exist
```

but then ALL tests run, regardless of the (non-existent) tags that I reference.

I get:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec --tag smoke_test_not_present_this_does_not_exist

Run options: include {:focus=>true, :smoke_test_not_present=>true}

All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:focus=>true, :smoke_test_not_present=>true}
.......................^C
Exiting... Interrupt again to exit immediately.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that I had:

```
config.filter_run focus: true
config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
```

in spec_helper.rb